# Define pyspark table with column type as timestamp

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to create a PySpark dataframe for some unit testing. One of the columns in the dataframe needs to be of the type `TimestampType`. I have the following code to define the dataframe:

```
spark = (SparkSession
            .builder
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("Unit-tests")
            .getOrCreate())

data = [
            ("2023-04-25 00:00:00", "A", 100.5),
            ("2023-04-26 00:00:00", "A", 110.0),
            ("2023-04-28 00:00:00", "A", 105.0),
            ("2023-04-27 00:00:00", "B", 50.5),
            ("2023-04-29 00:00:00", "B", 55.5),
        ]

schema = StructType([
            StructField("time", TimestampType(), True), \
            StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
            StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)
        ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
            data=data,
            schema=schema
        )
```

However, this gives me an TypeError:
`field time: TimestampType() can not accept object '2023-04-25 00:00:00' in type`.

I know a work around which is to initially define the `time` column as a `StringType` and then afterwards cast it to a `TimestampType` by adding this line of code:

`df.withColumn("time", col("time").cast(TimestampType()))`

But this seems like a rather cumbersome way of doing it. How can I define it directly in the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because [TimestampType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType.html) expects a `Timestamp` type and not `str`. This can be derived by using `datetime` in Python.

You just need to define your data like:

```
from datetime import datetime
spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .master("local[*]")
        .appName("Unit-tests")
        .getOrCreate())

data = [
        (datetime.strptime("2023-04-25 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "A", 100.5),
        (datetime.strptime("2023-04-26 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "A", 110.0),
        (datetime.strptime("2023-04-28 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "A", 105.0),
        (datetime.strptime("2023-04-27 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "B", 50.5),
        (datetime.strptime("2023-04-29 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "B", 55.5),
    ]

schema = StructType([
        StructField("time", TimestampType(), True), \
        StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
        StructField("value", DoubleType(), True)
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(
        data=data,
        schema=schema
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves my problem mostly, but I noticed that the timestamps are converted to another time. So instead of 00:00:00 the time is 02:00:00 - do you know of this issue?

Comment: Hey @andKaae, Did you resolve the issue with the time? If not can you share the code snippet which is causing the time shift? One quick fix is to use the `replace()` method to replace the hours and seconds. It is not the most optimal solution. I can help you further if you can share the exact code snippet which is causing the problem.